# Prove that the repetition code is the only linear code with parameters $[n,1,n]$

Tags: coding-theory

I have to prove that the repetition code is the only linear code with parameters $[n,1,n]$, up to equivalence of codes.

In order to show this, is it enough to say that equivalent codes have the same parameters (I already proved this), thus any $[n,1,n]$ code is equivalent to the repetition code, and therefore the repetition code is the only linear code with parameters $[n,1,n]$, up to equivalence of codes?

This seems like a rather silly question to ask on a homework assignment, do you think I'm supposed to first prove that the repetition code has indeed these parameters?

Comment: It's not a silly question, it's a simple question. There's a difference.

Comment: The $[n,1,n]$ repetition code is _unique_ and does not have any _distinct_ codes that are _equivalent_ to it.